# 「量子コンピュータ」はオフトピック?

Tags: 討議, 話題の範囲

今現在、自分が投稿した次の質問がオフトピックとしてクローズされています。 [量子コンピュータが通信系(とくに ssl, aka https) に与える影響は?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/40949/754)

これは、オフトピックなのでしょうか?

というのも、クローズ理由が「範囲が広すぎる」もしくは「(もろもろの理由で)主観的な意見しか集まらない」であるならば、まだわかるのですが、「オフトピック」でのクローズが、少し意外だったので質問しています。

Comment: 考えると程度問題のようにも思えてきました。たとえば [DNA コンピュータ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%94%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF)に関する質問がオフトピックかどうかと言われると、私にも自信がありません。個人的にはオントピックにしたいですが、それは私が現状アカデミック寄りだからかもしれません。。。

Comment: 全体的に、「オフトピックではない」なので、上記質問を再オープンしました。

Comment: mjyさんの回答にもありますが、レビューがコミュニティーの総意だと思うのでレビューせず再オープンするのは違うかと思います。

Comment: @Myaku 仰る通りなので、再度クローズいたしました。

Answer (score 5):

（本論とずれますが、モデレータ権限で再オープンになったことに関してです。独立した議論が必要であれば別にMeta質問として投稿し直します）

---

ここで「オフトピックではない」という意見が優勢であるのは事実ですが、再オープンへの投票という手続きを飛ばしてよいケースかというと、違うと思います。
クローズや再オープンという操作において、一般ユーザーによる投票を飛ばしてモデレータ権限を行使してよいのは、そもそも議論にならない程度に行うべきことが自明なケースのみと考えます。

今回に関しては、再度クローズすることを提案します。その上で私が再オープンに投票し、レビューキューに乗せます。

Comment: 仰る通りなので、再度クローズいたしました。

Answer (score 4):

私はオントピックだと思います。

ヘルプセンターの[「ここではどのようなトピックについて質問できますか?」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)によると、スタック・オーバーフローでは **おおまかにいって** 以下の質問がオントピックです。

> - プログラミング上の具体的な問題、または
> - アルゴリズムに関する問題、または
> - プログラマーがよく使うソフトウェアに関する問題であり
> - ソフトウェア開発に固有の、実際的で回答可能な問題である

まず、今回のご質問は SSL や暗号系という、プログラミング上で実際に登場してくるアルゴリズムに関するご質問です。「技術の発展によって暗号の安全性がどのように変化するだろうか」という話題は、当然出てくる疑問だと思います。

また、量子コンピュータや量子通信路に関する質問がソフトウェア開発に関係しないとは思えません。実用的な量子システムの開発が（アカデミアだけでなく企業においても）ますます進んでいる昨今において、量子システムについての質問は practical だと思います。

ちなみに、本家 Stack Overflow においても [quantum-computing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quantum-computing) というタグがあり、いくつかの質問が投稿されています。たとえば ["Quantum Computing and Encryption Breaking"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2768807/5989200) という質問は、今回のご質問と内容が被っています。

以上の理由から、私は今回のご質問はオントピックだと考えています。

Answer (score 3):

**オフトピック** ではないでしょうか。

[どのような質問は避けるべきですか?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) に

> 自分が直面している実際の問題に基づいて、実用的で回答可能な質問のみをしてください。...

とあるように、

- その問題が実際に起きている

ことが、大前提だと思います。

「〜していったとして、〜にどれぐらいの影響を及ぼしますか?」は前提が仮定であり、どのような問題が起きると予測されるか聞いているだけです。予測の回答が、正しい（もしくは将来の時点で正しかった）と、いつ、なぜ判断できますか？　実際に抱えた問題もなければ、解決したといえる基準も見当たらないと思います。

Comment: うーん、難しいですね。規準についてですが、私は今回のご質問は計算量クラスと暗号理論の問題に帰着できると思っていて、すると **数学的に** 今どこまで分かっているかが回答可能だと感じました。特に今回のご質問は「どのような新しい暗号系が生み出されますか？」ではなく「既存の暗号系がどうなりますか？」だということに注意が必要でしょう。／対して、今寄せられている2つの回答がどちらも、第三者が検証可能な理由が与えられていない「予測」であり、正しさを評価しにくくなってしまっていることは、その通りだと思います。

Comment: 解決すべき問題があるかどうかについてですが、二桁 qubit を持てる量子コンピュータが物理的に作れたというニュースが見られるようになった近年において、それが暗号にどう影響するかという問題は実際に起きているのではないでしょうか。また、暗号はその性質上、破られてしまってからでは遅いということも、これが現実的な問題であると立脚するための理由になると思います。

Comment: 逆に、どう質問を書き換えれば dokubeko さんとしてもオントピックにできるだろうか考えてみています。たとえば「〜は **将来** どのぐらいの影響を及ぼしますか？」ではなく、「〜は将来どのぐらいの影響を及ぼすだろうと **現状** 考えられていますか？」だと、解決したといえる規準が分かりやすくなると思いました。

Comment: **自分が直面している** というのが重要だと思います。これはもしかしたら「量子コンピュータの存在がプログラマとしての私に影響を与えそうだ」でOKかもしれないし、「現在、量子コンピュータを使っていてこのような問題が起きた」でなければ認めない人もいるかもしれないです。じぶんは後者なのでオフトピックと考えます。実際に起きた問題の直接の当事者でない質問が横行するとノイズになりそうだと感じています。

Comment: オントピックにするためには「（暗号化の解除など）は現在の量子コンピュータで実現できていますか？　できていない場合、どのような課題に実際に取り組んでいますか？」といった今現在の事実を量子コンピュータの開発者やユーザに尋ねる方向がよいと思いますが、質問者が実際に問題を抱えているわけではないので、この場合でもじぶんはオフトピックと考えると思います

Comment: 「自分が直面している実際の問題に基づいて」は原文ではshouldで、これをmustと捉えてしまうと扱えるトピックを必要以上に狭めている気がします。

Comment: 原文の表現は関係ないですね。問題を全体化するなら話は別ですが **この事例では** そこがshouldでもmustでも同じです

Comment: 翻訳文の解釈の飛躍を指摘していまして、原文は関係ないのですね。自分は理解に苦しみます。また、オントピック／オフトピックは https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic に書かれていることが全てではないでしょうか。

Comment: **この事例では** 関係ないですね

Comment: この事例が特別である理由を説明していただけますか。

Comment: 「問題の前提条件が仮定」「将来予測のため、現在は回答の正しさを検証することができない」。そのため **質問の形をした雑談** にしかなっていません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。その点は同意できます。その場合、オフトピックよりも「質問内容がはっきりしない」等で”改善待ち”にしてその後"クローズ”が相応しいと考えます。

Comment: 質問内容ははっきりしてますよ。その内容が実際に問題ですらないからオフトピックだと考えます。テーマや分野が外れているからという話じゃありませんので

Comment: 問題ではない→オフトピックという飛躍は理解できません。 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask に書かれている"自由形式の仮定的な質問をしている:「もし ______ が起きたらどうしますか?」”に該当するという指摘であれば正しいですが、それはオフトピックではなく質問の改善を求めるべきです。

Comment: この事例ではただの仮定的質問ではなく求めている回答も正しさが検証不可能です。それでもオントピックに戻したいなら実際にオフトピックに投票した人や質問を復活させる権限のある人に働きかけてください。じぶんの考えは本文に書いてある通りで何も変わりません

Comment: SOのオントピックの要件に「回答の検証可能性」があることは初耳でした。

Comment: それは問題として成立してない理由です。曲解して粘着しないでください。迷惑です

Comment: どこかでも見ましたが、自身に起こっていない質問を投げれないとするとセキュリティなどの事前対策系の質問ができず全滅しますね。それは困るということで飛躍しすぎない範囲での将来的な質問は日本語版SOでは受け入れられていると思ってました。

Comment: そうは言ってないですけど、そう受け取るならそれでいいですよ。このトピックとそれらの質問を同一視するなら、説明しても無駄みたいなので。オントピックに戻してあげればいいと思います

Answer (score 2):

現在の質問の量を考えると、オフトピックの運用は厳しすぎると思います。別件でも書いたことですが、英語版についてはジャンルごとに複数のサイトがあるので個々のサイトではオフトピックの基準が厳しくても問題ありませんが、日本語版はそうではありません。その観点でこの質問がオフトピックとすることも反対です。